# In a co-countable topology over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

The question given is In a co-countable topology over $\mathbb{R}$  There is no sequence of Rationals number that converges to $\sqrt 3$

**The solution i tried**- Here the given topology is co-countable i.e every set in this topology has countable complement , I try to prove it with contradiction ,Let sequence of rational converges to $\sqrt 3$, Let $U$ be the open set around  $\sqrt 3$ in Topology then  $\;U^{c}\;$ is countable ,Further i am not getting how to proceed further

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Because $\Bbb Q$ is countable, the set $U = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ is an open set in co-countable topology (its complement is $\Bbb Q$) and $\sqrt{3} \in U$ because it's irrational.

So $\sqrt{3}$ has an open neighbourhood that contains **no** points from the rationals so no sequence from the rationals can converge to $\sqrt{3}$.

In fact, something much stronger is true: suppose $(x_n)$ is any sequence in $\Bbb R$ in the co-countable topology and suppose the sequence converges to $x$.

Define $C=\{x_n: x_n \neq x\}$, which is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ so $O:=\Bbb R \setminus C$ is open by definition.

It's clear that $x \notin C$ so $x \in O$ and so by convergence:

$$\exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n \ge N: x_n \in O$$

But $x_n \in O$ is only possible when $x_n=x$ (otherwise $x_n \neq x$ and $x_n \in C$), so

$$\exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n \ge N: x_n = x$$

so $x_n$ is an eventually constantly-equal-to-$x$ sequence. This proves that if $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ and $x_n \to x$ then $x \in A$, for any $A \subseteq \Bbb R$, so all subsets of $\Bbb R$ in the co-countable topology are sequentially closed. In particular no irrational sequence can converge to a rational, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The set of all irrational numbers is an open set on this topology containing $\sqrt 3$. But there is no rational number in this neighborhood, so there is no sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: That means my supposition in the beginning  is wrong ,Because $Q^{c}$ is uncountable   in topology so no rational number in topology?